# Jquery 3.4.1 .on() "click" not firing when selector contains id and class

Tags: jquery, cordova, bootstrap-4

I am following a tutorial about using Cordova that utilises Jquery 3.4.1 and Bootstrap 4.4.1.

The tutorial is a few years old so before I try contacting the tutorial's author, I thought I'd give "SO" a try! (link to tutorial: http://codingfix.com/anatomy-of-a-cordova-application-navigation-system-the-top-navigation-bar/)

I'm assuming this has nothing to do with Cordova, and probably not with Bootstrap either, a is purely Jquery related, but I thought I'd give you the context.

Issue: I have a menu at the top of the page. When I run the App and tap the menu nothing is happening.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#cfx-topbar .cfx-topbar-menu', function() {
  alert("clicked!");
  var target = $(this).data('index');
  $('.carousel').carousel(target);
  switch (target) {
    case 0:
      //do here stuff specific to the view such as loading data...;
      break;
    case 1:
      //do here stuff specific to the view such as loading data...;    
      break;
    case 2:
      //do here stuff specific to the view such as loading data...;
      break;
    case 3:
      //do here stuff specific to the view such as loading data...;
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
#cfx-topbar {
  background: #689F38;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 3;
}

cfx-topbar-menu {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cfx-topbar">
  <ul id="cfx-topbar-menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-index="0"><i class="material-icons">dashboard</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-index="1"><i class="material-icons">group_work</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-index="2"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-index="3"><i class="material-icons">share</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This code will not fire.

What I have tried:

If I remove '.cfx-topbar-menu' from the selector...

```
$(document).on('click', '#cfx-topbar', function () {
```

It fires.

I'm sure there is a real simple reason why this isn't working but I've searched online and can't find anything that fits my dilemma, and it's in a tutorial. Maybe Jquery libraries have changed and this combination has been superseded?

Comment: Thanks for being so quick in responding. The issue was the "click" wasn't firing. OK, swapping the '.' to '#' does make it fire. Thanks. However, the next line: '$(this).data('index')' returns "undefined", with "this" being a HTMLUListElement object, and is not returning the "data-index" attribute set on the <li> element that was clicked. Is there another simple reason why 'target' isn't being populated correctly?

Comment: You're selecting the wrong element. The data attribute is on the `a` not the `li`

Comment: Thanks Rory. The final selector now looks like this: '#cfx-topbar #cfx-topbar-menu a'

Comment: I can't see how I can vote for you as you have not posted an "answer". If you do so I can set it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues here. Firstly the attribute you're trying to select by is an `id`, not a `class`, so the selector should be `#cfx-topbar-menu` not `.cfx-topbar-menu`. Secondly the `data` attribute is on the child `a` element of `#cfx-topbar-menu` so you need to include that in the selector. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#cfx-topbar #cfx-topbar-menu a', function() {
  var target = $(this).data('index');
  console.log(target);
});
```

```css
#cfx-topbar {
  background: #689F38;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 3;
}

cfx-topbar-menu {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cfx-topbar">
  <ul id="cfx-topbar-menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-index="0"><i class="material-icons">dashboard</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-index="1"><i class="material-icons">group_work</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-index="2"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-index="3"><i class="material-icons">share</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css is missing a . before the class name and your UL has an id but you are trying to invoke a class.

Try: $(document).on('click', '#cfx-topbar #cfx-topbar-menu', function() { ……

Or change the UL ID to class.

HTH